Vue3 project created with vue-cli not working after building
I've created a vue3 project using "vue create 'my-project'", using the default settings, and it´s ok, if I serve it, it works perfectly. When I build it, it gets done successfully but when I try to open the index.html on the browser nothing happens and I get these errors consoled:

"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUNDUnderstand this error
app.4a6fa159.js:1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUNDUnderstand this error
app.2cf79ad6.css:1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUNDUnderstand this error
/C:/favicon.ico:1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"`.

It makes no sense since I just created the project and built it, without any modification, so it's supposed to work.
I'm using

node v20.14.0;
npm 6.14.18; and
@vue/cli 5.0.8.


vue create

is the wrong obsolete CLI that you should NOT be using, unfortunately.

Following the current official docs, you should be using
npm create vue@latest


Also, you still need to serve the files once built, you cannot just open the project in your browser without a server.

Thanks Kissu, I've created the project again, this time using "npm init vue@latest", it has created a new projetc, I've built it again, and it didn't work again. I understand that, after I bult it, I just zip de content of the dist folder and if I upload it on a server it´s supposed to work, right? Or am I missing something?

No this is not how it is supposed to work. I never heard or shipping something zipped either. Honestly, give a try to Netlify. Connect it to your Github repo, give it npm run build for your build instructions and you're done. You need a server even to run a static app, to serve it and have the HTTPS protocol kicking in. Netlify does it with in a very simple way. You could even drag and drop you build there. A server will usually not have such a setup by itself unfortunately.

Netlify asks me to pay for a domain, I just would like to deploy my project and share the link with my team mates, do you have some tip?

@user23643630 no need to pay for a domain. Share the netlify.app one for free. Not as pretty but who cares.

Because vue-cli build bundle in the html, the assets was the absolute path , but you open the index.html file directly can't visit directly
First
npm install http-server -g

Second
go to dist dir
http-server

Now visit the http://localhost:8080

But even if I upload on a host site I get those errors. I've tested already using "yarn serve" and it works fine.

@user23643630 where do you host it? Try on Netlify.
